# React ternary operator - cannot render component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using ternary operator and I need to render a component. Here is what I have tried:

`{count: item.count ? item.count + <Chip/> : '❂'}`

`` {count: item.count ? item.count + `${<Chip/>}` : '❂'} ``

`{count: item.count ? item.count + (<Chip/>) : '❂'}`

Instead of rendering the component, I get `[object Object]`

Comment: why are you adding `item.count` with `Chip` component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of `React.Fragment`

```
{count: item.count ? <React.Fragment>{item.count}<Chip/></React.Fragment> : '❂'}
```

The reason it doesn't work in your case is because you are trying to concatenate values which essentially does string conversion of component which is the not the same as a rendered component

Answer (score 2):

Or just wrap it in a `<div />` element. JSX should always be wrapped in one root tag. Fragment is also an option, as said above.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to render a `Chip` component or `❂` depending on the `item.count`.

I would suggest using modern `React.Fragment`, like this:

```
{item.count ? <>
  <Chip />
  :
  <span>❂</span>
</>}
```

(I wrapped ❂ in a span purely for clarity)

If you want to display the count first, try this:

```
{item.count ? <>
  <>
    {item.count}<Chip />
  </>
  :
  <span>❂</span>
</>}
```

If you want to render Chip one per item.count, then use a loop in the first part.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that by using `+` you want to display both the `item.count` number and the `Chip` component. But I think that by using `+` javascript will call `toString` on these objects, since adding them doesn't really make sense.

To display both the item count and chip I suggest you try using [React Fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html).

```
{count: item.count ? <>{item.count}<Chip/></> : '❂'}
```